# SUMPRODUCT, Multiple criteria, IF, Blanks treated as 1

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, sumproduct

I've done quite a bit of googling, but am having difficulty combining different formulas together. I've tried to be as detailed as possible in describing what I want to achieve.

[image: Here is the table]

**Context:**

- There's a table of items with **prices** (column B) and **quantities (Qty)** (column C).
- Any input in the **exclusions** column (column E) signifies whether that particular row is excluded from any/all promotions.
- In the Discounts table, **Minimum** (column H) refers to the minimum order total that must be met or exceeded in order to be eligible for the **discount** (column I).
- I would like to **delete Column D** (not just hide it), which is included for illustrative purposes only.
- If it makes a difference, I'm doing this on Google Sheets.

**Looking for one formula in cell H5 that incorporates the following criteria:**

- Any input in column H indicates that row's discount is active. If column H is blank, then that row's discount is inactive.
- If no discounts are active (i.e., column H is empty), then do nothing and leave the cell H5 blank.
- Only one discount can be active at a time. If both are active, then H5 will remain blank. (H2 and H3 both have numbers in them right now for the sake of the example.)
- If **Discount 1** is active *and* the minimum order total in column H is met, then H5 should show me a number that is the sum of rows with exceptions (i.e., sumproduct of columns B and C in rows with something in column E, treating blanks in Qty as 1), divided by the order total (sumproduct of columns B and C, still treating blanks in Qty as 1), multiplied by the discount in I2 ($10). This pro-rates the discount across the whole order, reducing the discount by the proportion of excluded rows. i.e.,
  `(B3*1+B6*C6+B8*C8)/D12*I2 = $8/$27*$10 = $2.96`
- If **Discount 2** is active *and* the minimum order total is met, then H5 should show me a number that is the sum of rows with exceptions, divided by the order total, multiplied by the product of the discount percentage in I3 and the order total. i.e.,

```
(B3*1+B6*C6+B8*C8)/D12*(I3*D12) = $8/$27*(0.1*$27)
```

**What I have so far:**

- To get the total cost of this list of items, while treating any blanks in the Qty column as a 1 by default, I found the formula below in my search. (Truthfully, I don't understand how the above formula works, particularly because sumproduct(isblank(C2:C11)+C2:C11) gave me the same result despite not incorporating column B.):

```
=sumproduct((isblank(C2:C11)+(C2:C11)),B2:B11)`
```

- To account for the different discounts, I've come up with the below:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(E2:E11,"<>"&"")>0=TRUE,IF(AND(H2="",H3=""),"",IF(AND(H2<>"",H3<>""),"",IF(AND(H2<>"",H3="",D12>=H2),sumif(E2:E11,"<>"&"",D2:D11)/D12*I2,IF(AND(H2="",H3<>"",D12>=H3),sumif(E2:E11,"<>"&"",D2:D11)/D12*I3*D12)))))
```

- I'm thinking I can replace all instances of D12 with my first sumproduct formula above.
- **Missing:** However, I'm getting stuck on how to replace "sumif(E2:E11,"<>"&"",D2:D11)" with something like a sumproduct formula of B and C **with the added criteria** of only summing rows where something is in column E. My confusion is in part because I don't understand how that first sumproduct formula works to be able to incorporate any "IF" statements.

I'm also open to other suggestions if there's a better way for me to go about this. Thank you in advance for your time!

**Edit:**

- **Clarifying desired outcome:** Currently, this section of my formula sumif(E2:E11,"<>"&"",D2:D11)=8. I would like to replace all references to column D in this, and rely on a sumproduct of columns B and C only. It should still equal 8.
- The results in cell H5 depend on what happens in the Discounts table.

  - **If H2=$20 and H3 is blank**, H5=$2.96, which is H5=sumif(E2:E11,"<>"&"",D2:D11)/D12*I2
  - **If H3 = $20 and H2 is blank**, H5=$0.80, which is H5=sumif(E2:E11,"<>"&"",D2:D11)/D12*I3*D12
  - **If H2 and H3 are both blank**, H5=""
  - **If H2 and H3 are both not blank**, H5=""

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | **Item** | **Price** | **Qty** | **Total Cost** | **Exclusions** |  | **Type** | **Minimum** | **Discount** |
| **2** | Item 1 | $1 | 10 | $10 |  |  | Discount 1 | $20 | $10 |
| **3** | Item 2 | $1 |  | $1 | a |  | Discount 2 | $20 | 10% |
| **4** | Item 3 | $1 |  | $1 |  |  |  |  |  |
| **5** | Item 4 | $1 |  | $1 |  |  | **Result:** | **FORMULA HERE** |  |
| **6** | Item 5 | $1 | 5 | $5 | abc |  |  |  |  |
| **7** | Item 6 | $1 |  | $1 |  |  |  |  |  |
| **8** | Item 7 | $1 | 5 | $5 |  |  |  |  |  |
| **9** | Item 8 | $1 |  | $1 | ddd |  |  |  |  |
| **10** | Item 9 | $1 |  | $1 | efg |  |  |  |  |
| **11** | Item 10 | $1 |  | $1 |  |  |  |  |  |
| **12** |  |  |  | **$27** |  |  |  |  |  |

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: Your question can be greatly improved if you add a table to the question. [Tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) are a better alternative than spreadsheets to show your data structure.  If you share spreadsheets, make sure to also add images of your sheet to avoid closure of your question, as questions here must be [self](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455/) [contained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149892). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), when you share Google files.

Comment: `are markdown tables limited to three rows?` Nope. If you edit whatever you can, We can fix the formatting.

Comment: I didnt read the whole thing yet but why are `price × null_QTY = 1` ? also when and how do those Discounts kick in ?

Comment: @player0: Sorry if it was misleading. price x null_QTY ≠ 1. I would like null_QTY alone = 1. e.g., if there is a number in the price column, but nothing in the QTY column, we are going to assume that the QTY is 1. Hope this helps clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> formula of B and C with the added criteria of only summing rows where something is in column E

try:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(B2:B11, C2:C11, E2:E11<>"")
```

[image]

---

### update:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(B2:B11, IF(C2:C11, C2:C11, 1), E2:E11<>"")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your comment player0! However, the new replacement formula should result in an answer of 8 because I want the sumproduct of rows where E is not blank, so, rows 3, 6, 9, and 10, or B3*C3 + B6*C6 + B9*C9 + B10*C10 = 1*1+1*5+1*1+1*1=8.

Comment: @doubleu3513y answer updated